# How can the caller Task avoid having it's scheduler changed by a sub task that it flatMap's over

Tags: scala, task, scheduler, monix

I'm looking for a way in which a `Task` (i.e. outer scope) could execute a "subTask" using `flatMap` or something equivalent and make sure that any subsequent chained calls in the outer scope use the original scheduler.

Libraries and scala used:

- scala - 2.12.4
- monix - `"io.monix" %% "monix" % "3.0.0-RC1"`
- cats - `"org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.0.1"`

Example code:

```
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.execution.Scheduler
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
import cats.implicits._

object Test extends App {
  val io1 = Scheduler.io("io1")
  val io2 = Scheduler.io("io2")

  def taskEval(name: String) = Task.eval(println(s"Running eval Task [$name] on thread [${Thread.currentThread().getName}]"))

  def subTask: Task[Unit] = {
    taskEval("subTaskScope").executeOn(io2)
  }

  def outerScope(sub: Task[Unit]): Task[Unit] = {
    taskEval("outerScopeBefore") *> sub *> taskEval("outerScopeAfter")
  }

  def outerScopeTryProtect(sub: Task[Unit]): Task[Unit] = {
    taskEval("outerScopeBefore") *> (sub <* Task.shift) *> taskEval("outerScopeAfter")
  }

  val program1 = taskEval("programBefore").executeOn(io1) *> outerScope(subTask) *> taskEval("programAfter")
  val program2 = taskEval("programBefore").executeOn(io1) *> outerScopeTryProtect(subTask) *> taskEval("programAfter")

  Await.result(program1.runAsync, Duration.Inf)
// Running eval Task [programBefore] on thread [io1-573]
// Running eval Task [outerScopeBefore] on thread [io1-573]
// Running eval Task [subTaskScope] on thread [io2-574]
// Running eval Task [outerScopeAfter] on thread [io2-574] // << we don't shift back so we are stuck with the scheduler that is forces by subTask
// Running eval Task [programAfter] on thread [io2-574]

  println("------")
// Running eval Task [programBefore] on thread [io1-573]
// Running eval Task [outerScopeBefore] on thread [io1-573]
// Running eval Task [subTaskScope] on thread [io2-574]
// Running eval Task [outerScopeAfter] on thread [scala-execution-context-global-575] // we shift the scheduler but this restores the default scheduler
// Running eval Task [programAfter] on thread [scala-execution-context-global-575]

  Await.result(program2.runAsync, Duration.Inf)
}
```

The `subTask` method wants to do some asynchronous work on a dedicated scheduler (`io2`) so it forces async boundary an scheduler using `executeOn`.

The `outerScope` method is being executed in some program `program1` and it calls the `sub` (i.e. `subTask`) using `flatMap`. Since it does not to any explicit async boundary, if the `subTask` happens to change the scheduler (which it does), the rest of the `outerScope` will use the scheduler changed by the `subTask`. For this reason the call to `taskEval("outerScopeAfter")` is executed on the `io2` scheduler.

The `outerScopeTryProtect` tries to protect the scheduler it uses by introducing an async boundary (using `Task.shift`) after the `flatMap`ped `sub` (i.e. `subTask`). However, the async boundary (`Task.shift`) resets the scheduler to the default scheduler which will in this case go all the way back to the one used implicitly in `program2.runAsync`. This is not what we want, as we would like to be back to the scheduler that was used when calling `taskEval("outerScopeBefore")`, i.e. scheduler `io1`.

What I'm looking for is something like `Task[A].flatMap[B](f: A => Task[B]): Task[B]` that would execute the task produced by `f` in any way the `f` specifies (possibly using a different scheduler), but the resulting `Task` of the `flatMap` call will be back to the scheduler used by `Task[A]` before the `flatMap`.